# search words with accent without accent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a search on my website, and today I discovered that if a post has for example a description like "implicación en el proyecto" and I try to find this post using the word "implicacion" without the accent, I don't get any results, but if I try with "implicación" using the letter o with the accent, I found the post.

How can I fix this search, I need to find the post even if the user use the word without the accent.

This is the actual search on my model. I'm using postgresql for production.

```
find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ? OR title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search.capitalize}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search.capitalize}%"] )
```

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT

---

```
private

    def pg_strip_accents(field)
          "<<EOS
          translate(
            LOWER(#{field}),
            'âãäåāăąÁÂÃÄÅĀĂĄèééêëēĕėęěĒĔĖĘĚìíîïìĩīĭÌÍÎÏÌĨĪĬóôõöōŏőÒÓÔÕÖŌŎŐùúûüũūŭůÙÚÛÜŨŪŬŮ',
            'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu'
          )
          EOS"
        end


    def self.search(search)
        if search.present?
                where("#{pg_strip_accents('title')} LIKE :search OR #{pg_strip_accents('description')} LIKE :search", 
          :search => "%#{search.downcase}%")
        else
            find(:all)
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the postgresql `translate` function to do this as shown [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Strip_accents_from_strings,_and_output_in_lowercase).  Also, you can halve the amount of search terms if you convert both sides to upper or lowercase before testing them:

```
where(<<EOS
translate(
  LOWER(title),
  'âãäåāăąÁÂÃÄÅĀĂĄèééêëēĕėęěĒĔĖĘĚìíîïìĩīĭÌÍÎÏÌĨĪĬóôõöōŏőÒÓÔÕÖŌŎŐùúûüũūŭůÙÚÛÜŨŪŬŮ',
  'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu'
)
LIKE :search OR
translate(
  LOWER(description),
  'âãäåāăąÁÂÃÄÅĀĂĄèééêëēĕėęěĒĔĖĘĚìíîïìĩīĭÌÍÎÏÌĨĪĬóôõöōŏőÒÓÔÕÖŌŎŐùúûüũūŭůÙÚÛÜŨŪŬŮ',
  'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu'
)
LIKE :search
EOS }, :search => "%#{search.downcase}%")
```

As shown in the link, you can create a dedicated function to make this easier to reuse. Or you can use ruby code to do that for you:

```
def pg_strip_accents(field)
  <<EOS
  translate(
    LOWER(#{field}),
    'âãäåāăąÁÂÃÄÅĀĂĄèééêëēĕėęěĒĔĖĘĚìíîïìĩīĭÌÍÎÏÌĨĪĬóôõöōŏőÒÓÔÕÖŌŎŐùúûüũūŭůÙÚÛÜŨŪŬŮ',
    'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu'
  )
  EOS
end

where("#{pg_strip_accents('title')} LIKE :search OR #{pg_strip_accents('description')} LIKE :search", 
          :search => "%#{search.downcase}%")
```

Comment: PinnyM I'm getting this error undefined method `pg_strip_accents'. I'm trying the ruby code

Comment: Since you are calling it in a class method, the `pg_strip_accents` method need to accessible to the class itself.  Try defining it like `def self.pg_strip_accents(field)`.  Even better, you can put it in a separate module and extend any class to use that module using `extend ModuleName`.

Comment: Also, the `<<EOS` and `EOS` markers at the beginning and end of the method are in place of quotes (using block syntax) - you should remove the quotes that you have there now and make sure the final `EOS` marker are the first characters on the line (no spaces before them). Alternatively, remove these markers and all the line breaks to make the whole string fit on one line with the surrounding quotes.